# How to check graph definition in a tensorflow saved model

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, tensorrt

i'm workin with some models from the tensorflow object detection model zoo and performing optimizations with tf-trt.

My question is related to if is there a way to graphically or at least programatically to check the graph definition of a model (layer by layer). My goal is to compare the original network definition and after performig the trt optimizations.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You may try using Netron application to visualize your graph.
Simply upload your model using the browser session from the [netron github repository](https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron).